# passing Parameter in wf operation contract

Tags: workflow-foundation-4

i am Very new with wf service,i am using 4.0.i am creating the new project with all default properties,now the problem is how can is pass two  method parameters in my getdata operation contract(which is by default and it accept ony one value )

i want to do somethng like this

[operationcontract]

int getdata(int first,int second);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either select Parameters where you can enter multiple items, the easy way, or create a MessageContract with multiple body members and use that type in the Message option. The last options is more capable and more advanced, the fist is the better way to start if you don't have special messaging requirements.